# Can I use calc in margin top to push content lower in my text container

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to use calc to push my content down a specific amount of the parent container however I have tried the following

```
margin-top: calc(100% -50% - 150px) ;
```

the existing layout of the website is as follows roughly

```
<div class="header-featured-image"> 
    <div class="container" style="height: 75vh">
        <div class="page-titles-container">
            <div class="green-line-header"></div>
            <h1 class="main-page-title" id="page-title-h1">
                <?php if ($pageTitle) {
                    echo $pageTitle;
                } else {
                    the_title();
                } ?>
            </h1>
            <h3 class="second-page-title">
                <?php if ($pageSecondTitle) {
                    echo $pageSecondTitle;
                } else {

                } ?>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="featured-image-container">
            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="featured-image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php
}
```

}

this css is being added to the class .page-title-container

I am not sure if I am going about this the wrong way or if my understanding of calc is flawed any support would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding a space in front of 50% will probably fix it.

Comment: @Gerard thank you that fixed I thought it would something stupid I would miss thank you! if you post that as an answer I can mark it as correct